# receive index of nav element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to receive the index of the li element. I'm using this code, because I want to trigger several user inputs and deliver an action according to the classname and index of an clicked element. But I cannot get out the index:

[code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dKhLb)

JS

```
    $('body').on('click', function( e ){
        var trg = e.target;
    if ( trg.className.indexOf('button') > -1 ) {

      console.log(trg.index());
    }
});
```

html

```
<ul>
 <li class="button">0</li>
  <li class="button">1</li>
  <li class="button">2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Reason you do not use jQuery to do the check? `$('body').on('click', 'li.button' function( e ){ console.log($(this).index(); }`

Comment: use `$(document).on` [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L8csM/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a jQuery wrapper object for the event target and then call the [index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/) for that object

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if ($target.hasClass('button')) {
        console.log($target.index());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TMe8c/)

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function (e) {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```